# Android To Do List

Tags: java, android

In an android app, how would I go about saving data after the app is closed? I am trying to make a to-do list app, so I need the entries to stay after I close the app.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain you have done very little research on the subject as there is considerable  documentation on how to accomplish this. Let me get you started. You can use [SqliteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) to manage your SQLite database. Here is a good tutorial from [Android.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) You also have a few options other than the SQLite database built into android, like [these.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) I would not recommend using text or xml because with SQLite you will benefit from, well, sql related manipulations. For example, if you wanted to get a to-do by dates, SQLite allows you to query by dates. This way you filter out what you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

[Internal Storage & Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) are your friends ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use XML to represent each entry of your to-do list and then marshal and unmarshal them using JAXB.
Something like:

```
<task-list>
   <task remind="true">
      .. more tags ..
   </task>
  ... more <task> ...
</tasklist>
```

Comment: Can you provide some guidance as per how I could go about implementing  one of these in my application? I have my app currently set up to display information in a ListView but it clears the data in the ListView when the app is closed/reopened, and I would like this not to occur.

Comment: What information do you want stored in your XML document ? Make a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and let me know :)

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is use an `SQLite` Database.